# Receive all data using WSARecv

Tags: c, winsock2

I have a socket connected to a server.
In order to receive data from the server I use WSARecv,
but the problem is that I don't know what the size of the data.
If my buffer is smaller that the data sent, how can I know that there is more data? The return value was 0 and the flags parameters was 0 also.

result = WSARecv(s, &wsaBuf, 1, &numberOfBytesReceived, &flags, NULL, NULL);

Comment: According to MSDN, [WSAREcv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx), is a fancier [recv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) but the way you're using it, you don't benefit from its "extras" so you might use _recv_. On tha same page, in the __Remarks__ section lies the answer to your question: look for _MSG\_PARTIAL_ or _lpFlags_.

Comment: The flag MSG_PARTIAL should be returned by the lpFlags parameter. In my case it doesn't.

Comment: Probably because the message is small enough to fit in your buffer. Have you tried to pass a buffer smaller than the message that you are about to receive (I assume that at the other endpoint of the connection it's a server app also written by you and you can control what messages it sends to the client)? Try setting the _WSABUF_ member to a buffer of length 1.

Comment: The message I am about to receive is larger than my buffer.
The app in the other endpoint is an ftp server not written by me.

Comment: @CristiFati: I doing TCP I wonder which "*messages*" you are talking about, as TCP is stream oriented protocol.

Comment: How can I know when the stream ends?

Comment: For trivial case the stream ends when the sender closes the connection, else you need to define an/know the application level protocol.

Comment: Yes, my formulation was not quite correct, by message I meant what the other connection endpoint sent (using one or more _send_ or _WSASend_ or other funcs in the same family calls). I think that having a FTP server introduces extra complexity (because of the handshake). I'd suggest to create a small server app with a plain socket that listens for connections and when a client connection (this app) is accepted, the server sends some bytes which the client reads. I'd try sending using _send_ and _WSASendTo_ (w/wo _MSG_PARTIAL_ set) to see if it makes a difference at client endpoint (_WSARecv_).